# Scoped filtering over column range with & logic

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to find a method of filtering over a specific range of columns in a data frame to filter to rows that contain all elements of a character vector somewhere within that range of columns.

For example, if my column range was the one below:

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(10)

df <- tibble(
  a = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 10),
  b = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 10),
  c = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 10),
  d = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 10),
  e = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 10)
)

df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    a     b     c     d     e    
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#>  1 F     G     I     F     C    
#>  2 C     F     F     A     J    
#>  3 D     A     G     B     A    
#>  4 E     E     C     G     F    
#>  5 A     C     H     C     B    
#>  6 B     I     D     D     H    
#>  7 G     H     E     E     E    
#>  8 J     D     A     J     G    
#>  9 H     J     B     H     D    
#> 10 I     B     J     I     I
```

and I wanted to filter to rows that had at least one instance of `"A"` **and** at least one instance of `"C"` I could use `filter_at` twice to get the desired result:

```
df %>% 
  filter_at(vars(a:e), any_vars(. == "A")) %>% 
  filter_at(vars(a:e), any_vars(. == "C"))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   a     b     c     d     e    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 C     F     F     A     J    
#> 2 A     C     H     C     B
```

However , I'm trying to implement this in shiny where filter criteria comes as a vector `c("A", "C")` from a select input so is there a way I can do this with a single filter function using the vector?

Using  `%in%` won't work because it returns any rows with `"A"` **or** `"C"`

```r
df %>% 
  filter_at(vars(a:e), any_vars(. %in% c("A", "C")))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   a     b     c     d     e    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 F     G     I     F     C    
#> 2 C     F     F     A     J    
#> 3 D     A     G     B     A    
#> 4 E     E     C     G     F    
#> 5 A     C     H     C     B    
#> 6 J     D     A     J     G
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter within a loop:

```
filter_vec <- c("A", "C")

df_filtered <- df
for (f in filter_vec) {
  df_filtered <- filter_at(df_filtered,
                           vars(a:e),
                           any_vars(. == f))
}

df_filtered
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   a     b     c     d     e    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 C     F     F     A     J    
#> 2 A     C     H     C     B
```

Answer (score 0):

Fully `tidyverse` solution, though the `as_data_frame` and `$` calls seem ugly, and the nested functions aren't ideal, it is all handled in-pipe without a loop.

```r
target = c('A', 'C')

flag = df %>% 
  select(a:e) %>%  # If you have other columns, this does the same scoping
  rowwise %>% 
  do(as_data_frame(all(target %in% .))) %>% 
  .$value

df %>% filter(flag)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   a     b     c     d     e    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 C     F     F     A     J    
#> 2 A     C     H     C     B
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

I have long-ago recollections of `rowwise` calls being pretty slow for very long data.frames, but that'd be specific to your application.